# rest_framework returns Not found on url users/1/

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I need to return via rest_framework a users's detail
In my **views.py** i have UserViewSet class with

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = User.objects.all()
serializer_class = UserSerializer
pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
# permission_classes = (IsAdmin, )
search_fields = ('username',)
lookup_field = 'username'
```

my **urls.py** has this route

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from .views import UserViewSet
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/', include(auth_patterns)),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Postman returns Not found - what im doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `lookup_field` to username, you should use 'username' instead of ID.
So for example if your username is `admin`, use `api/users/admin`.
If you want to query it by the key, remove `lookup_field` entirely. That way, it will use the ID by default.